Why does tanh activation work better with Pytorch than with Keras?
I'm doing a neural network to recognize written Cyrillic letters, and I found out that, when I use tanh activation function, it works WAY better with PyTorch than with Keras.
Keras code:
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Lambda, BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ReduceLROnPlateau, EarlyStopping

a_param = 0.5
activation_type = 'tanh'

custom_activation = create_activation_function(a_param, activation_type)

input_shape = (100, 100, 4)

model = Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(784))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Lambda(custom_activation))

model.add(Dense(30))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Lambda(custom_activation))

model.add(Dense(10))
model.add(Lambda(custom_activation))

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-3),
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()

epochs = 30
batch_size = 128

lr_schedule = ReduceLROnPlateau(
    monitor='val_loss', factor=0.5, patience=3, min_lr=1e-6
)

early_stopping = EarlyStopping(
    monitor='val_loss', patience=3, restore_best_weights=True
)

history = model.fit(
    X_train, y_train,
    epochs=epochs,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    validation_data=(X_test, y_test),
    shuffle=True,
    callbacks=[lr_schedule, early_stopping]
)

Pytorch code:
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        # 100*100 изображения с 4 каналами (RGBA)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(100 * 100 * 4, 128)  # Входной слой для изображений 100x100 с 4 каналами
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(128, 64)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(64, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        # Изменение формы тензора в вектор длины 100 * 100 * 4
        x = x.view(-1, 100 * 100 * 4)
        x = torch.tanh(self.fc1(x))  # Использование tanh
        x = torch.tanh(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return torch.tanh(x)  # Применение tanh на выходе

While Keras the accuracy is around +/- 10%, while Pytorch is WAY above - up to 90%. What can be cause of it? Did I do something wrong or is it supposed to work this way?


What is create_activation_function doing and why not use keras.activations.tanh(x)?

How do you train the PT model? You also use early stopping and reduce lr on plateau? if not, remove it in the TF code too

batch norms in TF model but not in the PT model

adam's implementation is different in TF and PT if I'm not mistaken


